# Using HTTPS in my Django site

Tags: django, deployment, https

I have created a website using Django, and one of the requirements is that it must use HTTPS protocol.

I have already deployed it in a VPS using Apache without problems.

**What documentation/tips/snippet do you suggest me to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS/SSL has nothing to do with django as such, you must set apache configuration correctly using mod_ssl see

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html

and go through such articles

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/install-apache2-ssl/

Answer (score 0):

As Anurag said, this is apache related, you could try something like this in your httpd.conf or similiar configuration file (mod_rewrite as well as correctly installed certificate required):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, you don't need to do anything special for Django to work with SSL. If you want to enforce SSL, you can verify that the incoming request to a given view is over SSL by checking the `request.is_secure()` method (I have used this in the past to make a simple `require_ssl` decorator).